# .htaccess rewrite www to non-www except robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

Work fine but redirect `www.site.com/robots.txt` to `site.com/robots.txt`
I try to avoid robots.txt redirect. What need to add?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots\.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```